# HTML entity codes and server showing &amp; instead of &

Tags: html, css, entity

I'm trying to get a copyright symbol to show up and I'm using the entity code

```
&copy;
```

Problem is it's showing up as `"    &copy;"` instead of the copyright symbol.  When I firebug the code it's showing `&amp;copy;`

Is there some reason why it's making the & symbol show up as `&amp;` and how to prevent this?

Comment: Where are you writing that code?

Comment: Which editor are you using? Try using a plain text editor and try that again. Is it possible that you're using any "intelligent" html editor?

Comment: Sounds like something is escaping it. Where are you putting this? Plain .html file, your own application, something else?

Comment: Copy in the copyright symbol into your editing tool and see if it escapes html entities.

Comment: I bet you're using a WYSIWYG and you're writing that into the "design view" instead of the "code view".

Answer (score 3):

Wherever it is you're typing in `&copy;`, you must be typing it into a tool that's then helpfully encoding that for you (turning `&` into `&amp;`). You haven't given us any information to work with about what tool might be doing that, so we can't help, but if you put the characters `&copy;` in the actual HTML source of a page, when rendered it will come out as a copyright symbol. (Except inside the `title` element, but you won't see the encoded version there, so I know that's not what's going on.) This is an issue with the tools you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Something is re-encoding again your sentence... this is a double HTML encoding

Try to put the character (R) right away, it will be encoded for you apparently

How does this append in your case we don't have enough details

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want your html to look something like the following:

```
<div>&copy; 2011, Bob Cravens</div>
```